# Descriptions of error codes returned by regsvr32

Tags: documentation, error-code, regsvr32

Where can I find documentation that describes the meaning of error codes returned by regsvr32, such as 0x80070716?

Comment: For "usual" regsvr32 error codes (1 - 5) see [RegSvr32 exit codes documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22094309/264047)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is defined in `winerror.h`. Microsoft's reference is at [System Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381).

In my case the error code is 0x0716, which is 1814L. This error code corresponds to `ERROR_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND`.

Comment: The link maintenance on MSDN is very poor IMHO - the pages are effectively blank

Comment: Well that's unfortunate. I've edited this answer with an updated link.

Comment: In the case of 0x80070716 it's most likely that the resource (.rc) file doesn't include the RGS resource that regsvr32 needs to register and unregister the class in the Windows registry.

Answer (score 1):

I think it means you don't have adequate permissions.  See winerror.h:

```
#define FRS_ERR_INSUFFICIENT_PRIV        8007L
```

And [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb401631.aspx) on interpreting HRESULTs.

Edit:

Wrong bits, it's actually:

```
#define ERROR_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND    1814L
```

Comment: Ah, I think it's the lower two bytes which are significant: 0x0716.

Comment: The link is dead. I guess it was [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb446131.aspx)