# c# run RegSvr32 programmatically and get its DialogBox message

Tags: c#, winforms, process, regsvr32, redirectstandardoutput

I'm creating a C# Windows Form Application to register and/or unregister dlls programmatically. To do that, I simply use an instance of the `System.Diagnostic.Process` class. I would like to redirect both STDOutput and STDError inside a `textbox` element.

Using the following code, when I reg or unreg a managed .dll file (that is I use RegAsm.exe) I can obtain my redirecting goal.

In case of regsvr32.exe then my problem occurs: the Regsvr32's resulting DialogBox raises up (in both success or error cases)... but the message is totally blank.

[image]

So I have tried to use the RegSvr32's `/s` flag option... now the DialogBox does not raise up, but nothing becomes written inside the textbox.

Is there someone that can help me to solve this problem? I'm getting crazy! Thanks!

***A very curious note:*** As I'm stubborn, I've tried to register an unmanaged dll, using [this simple code](https://pcheruku.wordpress.com/2008/09/15/c-sample-to-register-dll-files-programatically/) (without the `/s` flag), implementing a C# Console Application... the RegSvr32 dialog box is pretty visible in both success and error cases.

[image]

So I've substituted the `Process` block code in the old code but the RegSvr32 dialog box still does not appear!!!

***Here is the Windows Form code:***

In the `Form1` class I implemented following delegates and methods to print inside the `Form1.textbox` element STDOutput and STDError:

```
void AppendLine( string line )
{
  if( textBox.Text.Length == 0 )
    textBox.Text = value;
  else
    textBox.AppendText( "\r\n" + value );
}

void OnOutputReceivedEvent( object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e )
{
  AppendLineMultiThread( e.Data );
}

void OnErrorReceivedEvent( object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e )
{
  AppendLineMultiThread( e.Data );
}

delegate void AppendLineMultiThreadHandler( string text );
private void AppendLineMultiThread( string line )
{
  // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread. If these threads are different, it returns true.
  if(InvokeRequired )
  {
    AppendLineMultiThreadHandler d = new AppendLineMultiThreadHandler( AppendLine );
    Invoke( d,  line );
  }
  else
  {
    AppendLine( line ); // call directly
  }
}
```

Inside the `Form1.Run()` method (it will be called when the user will click on my `RUN` button) each item registers both events, and then execute the Reg or Unreg process:

```
void Run()
{
  foreach( RegistererItem i in Config.RegItems )
  {
    i.ErrorReceivedEvent += OnErrorReceivedEvent;
    i.OutputReceivedEvent += OnOutputReceivedEvent;
    i.Execute();
  }
}
```

And here is the `RegistererItem.Execute()` method:

```
/// <summary>
/// The method used to Register or Unregister a dll.
/// </summary>
public void Execute()
{
  string exe = "depending on hidden parameters here I have 'regsvr32.exe' or 'RegAsm.exe'";
  string args = "depending on hidden parameters here I have '/codebase /s' or '/u /s'";

  try
  {
    using( Process reg = new Process() )
    {
      reg.StartInfo.FileName = exe;
      reg.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
      reg.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
      reg.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

      reg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
      reg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

      reg.ErrorDataReceived += OnErrorDataReceived;
      reg.OutputDataReceived += OnOutputDataReceived;
      reg.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
      reg.Start();
      reg.BeginErrorReadLine();
      reg.BeginOutputReadLine();
      //reg.WaitForExit(); // commented 'cause at the moment I don't care about it
    }
  }
  catch( Exception exc )
  {
    throw new Exception( exe + " " + args, exc );
  }
}

public delegate void DataReceivedEventHandler( object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e );
public event DataReceivedEventHandler ErrorReceivedEvent;
void OnErrorDataReceived( object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e )
{
  if( ErrorReceivedEvent != null )
    ErrorReceivedEvent( sender, e );
}

public event DataReceivedEventHandler OutputReceivedEvent;
void OnOutputDataReceived( object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e )
{
  if( OutputReceivedEvent != null )
    OutputReceivedEvent( sender, e );
}
```

Comment: Use its exit code: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22094309/1207195

Comment: Regsvr32.exe does *very* little, it loads the DLL you specified with LoadLibrary(), finds the DllRegisterServer() entrypoint with GetProcAddress() and then calls it.  Any output you see, like a dialog box, is provided by the DLL itself.  That this doesn't work well when you do this with the Process class, well, that happens.  Always set the ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory to the same directory that contains the DLL.  And never forget to ask for administrator privileges in your manifest.  If you still have trouble then you'll have to talk to the vendor or author of the DLL.