# Cannot register mshflxgd.ocx on Windows 10

Tags: com, vb6, installation

windows 10 version is 1709 Build 16299.15

mshflxgd version is 6.01.9816

I suspect this might be related to the kill-bit\phoenix bit but cannot verify. Every time I try and register it gives a "unable to register mshflxgd.ocx" message.

I've made sure I am in using \windows\syswow64\regsvr32 and putting the file in syswow64. Also running session and command prompt as admin.

Does regsvr32 log failures to a log file or is there anywhere I can look to see why registration fails?

Comment: Not at home, so I can't check myself at the moment, is this a standard ms flex grid or some kind of custom or third-party control?  Is this problem -after- a Windows update or during a migration - was it working before?

Comment: FWIW My copy in \Windows\Syswow64 is dated 2/16/2010 2:22 PM and 443,488 bytes.  I see that it's the Hierarchical Flexgrid control, so I started a new project and loaded that control with no issues.  I'm running the latest and greatest Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: The killbits only impact controls hosted in an IE page, MS Office, and a few other less common containers.  It sounds like you didn't install VB6 properly, or if this is a deployment issue then your installer is flawed.

Comment: No log but regsvr does [set an exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094309/regsvr32-exit-codes-documentation) although you would think that if a detailed error were available you would see it in the error msgbox.  You could also try loading the ocx via the components dialog in VB6/Office to see what happens.

Comment: @BillHileman - standard ms control. It works on win7 and on win10 v1709.16299.125. I'm still collecting version numbers but it has been difficult since the customers are just downgrading back to 7 and don't remember version of windows. And your dates\sizes for the ocx match mine

Comment: @Bob77 - This is on a client so no IDE. I'm also using regsrv32 to rule out problems with the installer